# Dynamic Forms with custom validation, should I use NoSQL or SQL for store?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
{
    "id": 1, // project id
        "form": [
    {
        "section": [ // each section's a page
            { // questions
                "titles": [], 
                "number": "1", //number of the question
                "description": "",
                "option": {
                    "isHide": false,
                    "isRequired": true
                },
                "input": {
                    "type": "radio", 
                    "contents": [
                        {
                            "text": "radio 1",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "radio 2",
                            "value": "2"
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "radio 3",
                            "value": "3"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "conditional-statements": [] //conditional statements, for example: hide this if user click 'yes' on the previous question
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I'm building a multi-step Dynamic Form with dinamic validations (multiple pages per section, it must have `previous`, `back` and `finish` buttons). The user must be able to dynamically create a form too.
After, I want to record what the user chose. Would you suggest using NoSql (Mongo) for such task rather than SQL?

Comment: Whatever makes you feel comfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using node.js, I would suggest using MongoDB. It works really well with node and also has a very developed Mongoose ORM that you should use. 
I have used both MongoDB and MySQL with node.js and the experience with MySQL wasn't good, because there aren't many ORM's and the ones available aren't good or don't have most of the desired features. And in my experience, you will want to use an ORM.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to store a variable structure in Document based database like `MongoDB`. In `MySQL` you would need to define a structure where you can then save all of your forms and it would take more effort. I suggest using NoSql here.

Answer (score 0):

If in your project there is nothing about any transactions of money then you should use MONGODB otherwise SQL.

WHY?

1. Mongodb isThe BASE Consistency Modeland SQL is The ACID Consistency Model
   [ACID vs BASE](https://neo4j.com/blog/acid-vs-base-consistency-models-explained/)
2. Like for transactions SQL is best because it gives result when transation held as mongodb is mostly use for eg - social projects where you are not worried about your likes , shares etc.

Thanks